# Error in Android Dependencies , while integrating FB-SDK 3.0

Tags: android, facebook

I have tried all the threads related to errors while integrating FB-SDK but was not successful , any answers are welcomed .

My Java Compiler is set to 1.6.

I get this error while integration the Facebook SDK to my App

[image]

it is giving me the error at that marked place as

```
path\facebook-android-sdk-3.0.2\facebook\bin(missing)
```

i get this error after added this by clicking OK .

[image]

Thanks in Advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before moving on, I recommend you to get latest Facebook SDK, because there are [some important changes](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/upgrading-from-3.0.2.b-to-3.0/) between yours (3.0.2) and 3.0.

Here's what I do to import Facebook SDK

1- Download the latest SDK, extract it to a directory, i.e. X. (~/X)

2- Open Eclipse, New Project -> Android Project From Existing Code, then browse and choose ~/X/facebook-android-sdk-3.0 as root directory

3- Select only "facebook" project and click finish

4- Right click to facebook project -> properties. Choose Compiler Compliance level as 1.6 from Java Compiler section

5- Create new android project, and set it's compliance level 1.6 as well. Also in Android section of Project Properties, Click add button, and choose facebook project (that we imported in Step 3)

6- Finally, Project -> Clean. For me this works like a charm all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if you have the facebook jar inside your fb-sdk/bin folder? If it's not there, do a **clean and build** procedure first in your **fb-sdk** folder. It will produce a facebook.jar file on your bin folder.
After that, then, you may already do another **clean and build** on your **main project** folder.